# Drupal error after creating new theme ,Undefined variable: hide_site_name and other similar error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I am new to drupal theme . I have created a direcory `mytheme` and added `mytheme.info` to it and copied other files from drupal's default theme directory . Now after editing the `page.tpl.php`, drupal is showing the errors below .

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 99 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 109 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: featured in include() (line 168 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 187 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_second in include() (line 212 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_first in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_middle in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: triptych_last in include() (line 220 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_firstcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_secondcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_thirdcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_fourthcolumn in include() (line 230 of C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes\mytheme\bartik\templates\page.tpl.php).
```

After searching on google, I have found that clearing cache will solve the problem . But even after clearing my cache,it remains the same !

Comment: see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37797/drupal-error-after-creating-new-theme-undefined-variable-hide-site-name-and-ot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally these errors occurred when you call a region in your `page.tpl.php` file that doesn't exist in the theme's `.info` file.

In your `page.tpl.php`:

```
$page['footer_firstcolumn'];
```

In your theme's `.info`:

```
regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
```

After rechecking all regions, don't forget to `flush the cache`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it partially worked I am now getting only two messages why?:                                            Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 99 of E:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\themes\jelly\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: hide_site_name in include() (line 103 of E:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\all\themes\jelly\page.tpl.php).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a fresh theme best practice is to use something like [Zen](http://drupal.org/project/zen/). It's blank and fully customizable.

As long as you follow the prescribed instructions, you will avoid nasty errors like the ones you have above

Answer (score 1):

i had almost the same problem of messages saying "Notice: undefined index: myIndex in include() (line n in some/path/myPage.tpl.php)" whe i was coding my custom sub-template

I kind of solved the problem using php's function isset() for every line told in the Notice message.

For example in your line 99 i would use:

```
if(isset(hide_site_name)){
    //use hide_site_name in the normal way
}
```

or in your line 168

```
if(isset( some_var[featured] )){
    //use "featured" index in the normal way
}
```

hope this helps someone as this helped me after a long time searching for a solution.
i never found the cause of this behavior btw.
sorry for bad grammar, if there's any.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after creating a sub theme and I followed the answer by Meiker and it worked great about including isset. But as I do not have a lot of experience with programing I ran into a snag with line 220 and multiple triptych in the same line.

> Notice: Undefined index: triptych_first in include() (line 220 of
>   C:\wamp\www\dtest\sites\all\themes

So I added isset like this:

```
if(isset($page['triptych_first']) || (isset($page['triptych_middle']) || (isset($page['triptych_last'])))) :
```

and did the same for similar error lines and now I do not have any more errors appearing.

I hope this helps others who are programming challenged.